# Count the pictures per row in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, lightbox, image-gallery

Im made a gallery in rails by creating a div for each image-url in the database in my view. I would like to add a feature, that the user can specify the pictures per row and the number of rows per page on my edit-page. The value will be written to the database and the pagination should than be dynamic using the calculated value (pictures_per_row * rows_per_page).

Problem: Im using images.each method in my view to loop through the pictures and create a div for every image in the gallery. So they are created one after another. Concerning the results are paginated, gives me a specific number for pictures per page. But how do I accomplish something like:

for gallery.image.each do a div, but after 5 divs, continue in new line.

I think the pagination isnt the problem here, because it will paginate whatever the database query delivers.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [each_slice](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice). Something like:

```
<% @gallery.each_slice(5) do |slice| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% slice.each do |item| %>
     <!-- Display images-->
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If it works with a variable this should do the job. I will try that tomorrow. Thx

Comment: It should do. 